# Image view should not move outside the its superview using UIPangesture

Tags: iphone

I am using a UIPangesture to move a imageview and this imageview is subview of of view of class, when I move imageview then it move outside its superview. I want to set the boundary of moving this imageview, means the imageview should move only inside its superview.

Answer (score 1):

i guess in the selector that is called by the pan gesture you are setting the view's center or origin accordingly to the point of the pan.

this is how your code should look in order to solve your problem:

```
- (void)thePanSelector:(id)sender{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint p = [recognizer locationInView:theSuperView];
    float boundedX = MAX(0,MIN(theSuperView.frame.size.width,p.x));
    float boundedY = MAX(0,MIN(theSuperView.frame.size.height,p.y));
    CGPoint boundedPoint = CGPointMake(boundedX,boundedY);
    view.center = p;
}
```

this code is untested so you may need to play a little with the values of boundedX and boundedY

Comment: @ajeet did you try this? how did you fix your problem?